# Azure Search search with slash

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'm using Azure Cognitive Search.

```
private async Task PerformSearchAsync<T>(SearchServiceDocumentsQueryParameters parameters, SearchClient searchClient, ICollection<T> outputCollection)
            where T : BaseSearchIndexObject
        {
            var searchResponse = await searchClient.SearchAsync<T>(parameters.SearchTerm, new SearchOptions
            {
                Filter = parameters.Filter,
                IncludeTotalCount = true,
                Size = parameters.MaxItemsCount
            });
            await foreach (var searchResult in searchResponse.Value.GetResultsAsync())
            {
                if(outputCollection.All(d => d.Id != searchResult.Document.Id))
                    outputCollection.Add(searchResult.Document);
            }
        }
```

Everything works fine until the search term contains slash. For example I am looking for order with number "1508/W/2020". When I search with SearchTerm = "1508" it works. When SearchTerm = "1508/W" it returns nothing. I tried escaping the slash with `\\` but it still doesn't work. Can you suggest me any solution?

Comment: Note that the correct escape sequence for a forward slash would be `\/`, not ```\\``` .

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer, as per [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)? It only takes you a few seconds, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The comment is correct. To escape `/`, you should use this format `\/` instead of `\\`.

For more details, you can refer to this [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax#escaping-special-characters) for special chars escaping.